# Анимация на css

Tags: html, css

```css
@keyframes form {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(-10deg)
  }
  75% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(1deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg)
  }
}

.form-auth {
  position: relative;
  width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 40px 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0.4px 6px 65px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  animation: form .6s ease-in-out;
}

.form-auth__title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-auth__descr {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}

.form-auth__input-field {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #636363;
}

.form-auth__input-field:focus {
  border: 2px solid #3e9ffd;
}

.form-auth__input-field--bottom {
  margin-bottom: 22.5px;
}

.form-auth__sign-in {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #3e9ffd;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom-control {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 22.5px;
}

.custom-control__input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-control__input:checked~.custom-control__label::before {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}

.custom-control__input:checked~.custom-control__label::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.custom-control__label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #636363;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.custom-control__label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #adb5bd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.custom-control__label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: no-repeat 50%/50% 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0.4px 6px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.logo__block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 27.5px;
  height: 27.5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.logo__block--orange {
  left: 28.5px;
  top: 15px;
  background: rgba(248, 145, 29, 0.8);
}

.logo__block--pink {
  right: 30px;
  top: 26px;
  background: rgba(209, 54, 156, 0.8);
}

.logo__block--blue {
  left: 28.5px;
  top: 42.5px;
  background: rgba(62, 159, 253, 0.8);
}

.logo__block--green {
  right: 30px;
  top: 53.5px;
  background: rgba(78, 191, 73, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <form action="" class="form-auth">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="logo__block logo__block--orange"></div>
      <div class="logo__block logo__block--pink"></div>
      <div class="logo__block logo__block--blue"></div>
      <div class="logo__block logo__block--green"></div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="form-auth__title">QCRM</h2>
    <p class="form-auth__descr">by SupportYourApp</p>
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" required autocomplete="off" class="form-auth__input-field">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required class="form-auth__input-field form-auth__input-field--bottom">
    <div class="custom-control">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control__input" id="chk">
      <label class="custom-control__label" for="chk">Remember me on this computer</label>
    </div>
    <button class="form-auth__sign-in" type="submit">Sign In to QCRM</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как реализовать такую анимацию как на видео. 
Анимацию основного блока сделал, а с мелкими проблемы.
https://youtu.be/dpxCtJczrYY

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: спасибо за награду, я так понял Вам подошло :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не идеально, но похоже

```js
setTimeout(e=>container.classList.add('activated'));
```

```css
#container {
    perspective: 800px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.squares {
    border-radius: 20%;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    box-shadow: 0 100px 100px 0 #0005;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 1s;
    perspective: 800px;
    transform-origin: 50% 40%;
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 80deg) translate3d(0, 0, 50px);
}

#container.activated .squares {
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0deg)translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 15px 0 #0005;
}

#container.activated .square {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.square:nth-child(1) {
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translate3d(-30px, -200px, 0) scale(1.5);
    background-color: rgba(254, 133, 0, 0.8);
    transform-origin: 150% 40%;
}
.square:nth-child(2) {
    top: 75px;
    left: 50px;
    transform: translate3d(0, -50px, 50px)scale(1.3);
    background-color: rgba(3, 154, 255, 0.8);
    transform-origin: 100% 40%;
}
.square:nth-child(3) {
    top: 50px;
    left: 75px;
    transform: translate3d(0, -150px, 40px) scale(1.4);
    transform-origin: -50% 40%;
    background-color: rgba(210, 58, 144, 0.8);
}
.square:nth-child(4) {
    top: 100px;
    left: 75px;
    transform: translate3d(0, -250px, 100px) scale(1.4);
    transform-origin: -50% 40%;
    background-color: rgba(62, 180, 68, 0.8);
}

.square {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="squares">
    <div class="square"></div> 
    <div class="square"></div>    
    <div class="square"></div>    
    <div class="square"></div>    
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov так а не поменялось ничего в плане анимации

Comment: Не точно выразился, в плане анимации, связанной с наведением мыши. С интерактивностью было интереснее.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov я тоже так сначала подумал, но в вопросе все же форма сама появляется..., решил подправить

Comment: Надо чуть-чуть подправить вопрос... :)